# how to write a VSTS query that shows the teams discussion counts?

Tags: azure-devops, reporting, kanban, azure-devops-rest-api

we want to write a query that displays the counts of users daily comments in VSTS tasks. How can we do that?

Which API should we use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [Work Item Comments REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/comments) that can query the comments, for example: `https://[account].visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems/[work item id]/comments?api-version=3.0-preview`.

So, you can build a app to do report with this REST API, you also can custom extension to show data with this REST API: [Write your first extension for VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/get-started/node)